# Copy animation data from one armature to another with Python

Tags: python, animation, armature, bones

I've been trying to write a script to copy animation data from an armature to another one, unfortunatly without success so far.

My situation is that i have :

- A mesh with it's armature that doesn't contain any animation, loaded from an `fbx` file
- An animation with the same skeleton definition as the `fbx` file, loaded from a `bvh` file

---

**Script attempt**

From what i understood, as the two objects doesn't share the same rest pose, i need to :

1. Add `COPY_TRANSFORMS` constraints to the *source* armature for each of it's bones
2. Loop over each *target* armature bone and copy rotation data from it's corresponding *source* bone

Here's what i tried :

```
def copy_anim_data(source_obj, target_obj):
    for bone in source_obj.pose.bones:
        ct = target_obj.constraints.new('COPY_TRANSFORMS')
        ct.influence = 1
        ct.name = bone.name
        ct.target = source_obj
        ct.subtarget = bone.name

    for i in range(0, 10):
        scene.frame_set(i)
        for bone in target_obj.pose.bones:
            source_bone = source_obj.pose.bones.get(bone.name)
            if source_bone is not None:
                bone.rotation_quaternion = source_bone.matrix_basis.to_quaternion()
                bone.keyframe_insert(data_path='rotation_quaternion')
```

Which seems to copy the rotation data properly, but the target animation looks distorted : it seems like the constraints doesn't have any effects.

---

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Thanks